# Server Client program undefined behavoir

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a server client chating program in linux. The code is not working as intended for some reason.

The problem is in client code, inside while loop, the compiler `doesn't wait at scanf` for taking input, instead it `sends some garbage data itself to the server`, in return the server also sends some data and `client program terminates`.

I can't figure out the problem due to my limited knowledge, your help will be appreciated alot.

**Server.c**

```
#define PORT 3690

#define MaxBufferLength 1024


int main()
{
    int sockFd, bytesRead, bytesSent;

    char buffer[MaxBufferLength];

    struct sockaddr_in server, client;


    server.sin_port= htons(PORT);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


    if(sockFd == -1)
        printf("Unable to open socket\n");


    int i = bind(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    if(i == -1)
        perror("Unable to bind\n");



    i = listen(sockFd, 1);

    if(i == -1)
        printf("Unable to listen\n");




    int connectionSocket = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    if(connectionSocket == 1)
        printf("connection established\n");


    while(1)
    {           
        bytesRead = recv(connectionSocket, buffer, MaxBufferLength, 0);

        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

        printf("Client said: \n     %s\n", buffer);


        scanf("\n\n = %s", buffer);

        bytesSent = send(connectionSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

        if(bytesSent == -1)
            perror("Failed to send a message");

        connectionSocket = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); // wait for connection again
    }


    close(sockFd);

    return 0;



}
```

Regards

Comment: Does it do this every time? Or only after your first message?

Comment: It happens every time.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use scanf() to print output (i.e. "Enter message:") to the user.  I don't think that's something scanf() can do; you'd be better off doing a printf("Enter message: "); fflush(stdout); scanf("%s", buffer); instead

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging information (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn to use a debugger (`gdb`). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). You may want to learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is almost fine except for one **MAJOR** thing, the `accept()` function.

1. The last argument of the accept function should be a `reference to size_t or int` variable containing size of the structure, where as you are passing the variable data as an argument. Turns out this results in `no connection between server and client`, that's why you are facing this undefined behavior.
2. I think you forgot the syntax of scanf :). `Don't display message in it for taking input`.
3. Last thing is add a null character at the end of the char array.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This might cause issue.

```
sizeof(struct sockaddr) ==>sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) or sizeof(server)

int connection = connect(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server) )
```

AND

```
scanf("Enter message: \n\n = %s", buffer); 
          |
          V 
printf("Enter message: ");
scanf("%s",buffer);
```

see [Networking and Socket programming tutorial in C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to terminate your `buffer` with

```
       buffer[N_from_scanf] = '\0';
```

before you send it.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that in client program the compiler doesn't wait for me to input something. It skips scanf and directly sends some garbage data then terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are indeed connecting properly between the client and the server, you're issue may in how you are using scanf() in both client.c and server.c. You should use printf for writing to stdout. You can also use fprintf() passing the socket descriptor directly to the function instead of using send() and fscanf with the descriptor to receive messages.